# what does 0x0 @ 0x196f2f0 mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, qt-creator

I have a variable which shows 0x0 @0x196f2f0 in the debugging session of qtcreator.  Does this mean that a pointer to NULL is being stored at memory address 0x196f2f0?

Comment: NULL is just a fancy way of saying `0` the above is zero in hex `0x0` = `0`(base 10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it means that variable stored at memory location `0x196f2f0` has the value `0x0`. If you're inspecting the variable, you can see its memory address and the value.

Comment: Which is to say, "yes."

Comment: hmm, the variable i have stored at that location is an array.  The strange thing is that doing array[i] is returning a value which would contradict the conclusion that it's storing zero (NULL).

Comment: @Mustafa and what yields `array[0]`? Is the array statically allocated?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Array Declaration: `pixels_ = new Pixel**[num_pixels_x_];`

Comment: That sounds strange. Is type of `pixels_` `Pixel**` (2D array)? If so, you need first to allocate rows (`pixels_ = new Pixel*[x]`) and then each row (`for (i = 0; i < x; i++) pixels_[i] = new Pixel[y];`). However, I'm just guessing here.

Comment: yes, it is a 2D array of `Pixel` objects and it is being allocated as you have indicated.  I made a mistake, it is being accessed using `pixels_[i][j]`.  In my previous comment I showed how it's instantiated (not declared).  It is declared as `Pixel*** pixels_` in the header file.

Comment: @Mustafa if this is the case then I guess something is not right with the debugger, as pixels_ pointer should not be 0 if it is allocated.